# Storybook - Why are my grid items being pushed so far to the right?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, storybook

I am trying to make a grid in HTML and CSS, but the grid items keep being squished to really small heights and they also are pushed really far to the right when I use Storybook. I've tried setting the height of the grid container manually and designed the layout then copied this code from the website - https://grid.layoutit.com/, so I don't see why it looks totally different.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.3fr 1.3fr 1.4fr 0.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
    gap: 5px 5px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "Edge1 B1 B2 Snub Edge2"
      "Edge1 B3 B4 Snub Edge2";
}
.Snub { grid-area: Snub; }
.Edge2 { grid-area: Edge2; }
.Edge1 { grid-area: Edge1; }
.B1 { grid-area: B1; }
.B2 { grid-area: B2; }
.B3 { grid-area: B3; }
.B4 { grid-area: B4; }
.grid-container * {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="Snub"></div>
    <div class="Edge2"></div>
    <div class="Edge1"></div>
    <div class="B1"></div>
    <div class="B2"></div>
    <div class="B3"></div>
    <div class="B4"></div>
</div>
```

I've also included a JSfiddle. The only issue in the fiddle is that the height is squished.

https://jsfiddle.net/zvcjktum/4/

Answer (score 1):

You have no content inside div's, so it takes as minimum space as it needs. As default `width` and `height` is set to `100%`, in this case it's `100%` of parent div, that no exists, so it's `100%` of `0px`. Your `fr` units are also relative, they works similar are percentages. The only real heights that exists in your css are:

- 2x `1px` from `border` (x2 cause you have 2 rows in your grid),
- `5px` from `grid-gap`.

So you have `9px` of height in total.

You can force it to take all the space, e.g. by adding `100vh`:

```css
.grid-container {
    height: calc(100vh - 15px); /* or just 100vh */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1.3fr 1.3fr 1.4fr 0.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 0.5fr;
    gap: 5px 5px;
    grid-template-areas:
      "Edge1 B1 B2 Snub Edge2"
      "Edge1 B3 B4 Snub Edge2";
}
.Snub { grid-area: Snub; }
.Edge2 { grid-area: Edge2; }
.Edge1 { grid-area: Edge1; }
.B1 { grid-area: B1; }
.B2 { grid-area: B2; }
.B3 { grid-area: B3; }
.B4 { grid-area: B4; }
.grid-container * {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="Snub"></div>
    <div class="Edge2"></div>
    <div class="Edge1"></div>
    <div class="B1"></div>
    <div class="B2"></div>
    <div class="B3"></div>
    <div class="B4"></div>
</div>
```